# MS Access and MySQL attempting to change the same record

Tags: mysql, adodb

This is an old issue in stack overflow, and i have tried all of the suggestions I can find.

1. Mysql database linked to ms access.
2. Windows 11 - new laptop
3. ms access database app that i have been carrying along with me for 20+ years.

I update data in access using a record set. see below

```
Public Sub updatedurations(indate As Date)

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim lasttime As Date

lasttime = 0

With rs
     .Open "Select * from tbldailytasks where taskdate = #" & _
        indate & "# order by starttime desc", _
     CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
               
     While Not .EOF
        If lasttime <> 0 Then
            !duration = lasttime - !starttime
            !endtime = lasttime
        Else
            !duration = 0
            !endtime = !starttime
        End If
        lasttime = !starttime
        
        .Update
        .MoveNext
     
     Wend
     .Close
End With

End Sub
```

At the .update I receive the error 'you and another user are trying to change the same record.'
No other forms are open in access.

this is the mysql table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbldailytasks` (
  `DailyTaskId` int NOT NULL,
  `todaystaskid` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `taskid` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `TaskDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `starttime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `endtime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `TaskDescription` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ClientId` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `ProjectId` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `BillableFlag` tinyint DEFAULT '-1',
  `DailyTaskAutoNo` double(15,3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `mytimestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DailyTaskAutoNo`),
  UNIQUE KEY `DailyTaskAutoNo` (`DailyTaskAutoNo`),
  KEY `ClientId` (`ClientId`),
  KEY `datetimeindex` (`TaskDate`,`starttime`),
  KEY `ProjectId` (`ProjectId`),
  KEY `ScheduleID` (`todaystaskid`,`DailyTaskId`),
  KEY `taskid` (`taskid`),
  KEY `tblDailyTasksScheduleID` (`todaystaskid`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `TaskDescription` (`TaskDescription`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=18454 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;
```

There is a primary key, there is a timestamp.

I am using mySql ODBC Connector 8.0.26 (NB: i had 8.0.27 installed, but this has issues that cause ms access to fail and 8.0.28 is not yet available.)

Any help is appreciated.

THanks,

Paul

Comment: have you tried an older version than 8.0,26

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have not tried that yet.  I may go that route, but will be trying the SQL suggestion by JNevill below.

Answer (score 1):

While not a direct answer to your question, I feel like this logic can be handled with a single UPDATE statement in mysql directly. Something like:

```
WITH updateCTE AS 
(
   SELECT DailyTaskID, 
      CASE WHEN LEAD(DailyTaskID) OVER (ORDER BY starttime DESC) IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as lastRecordInd,
      CASE WHEN LEAD(DailyTaskID) OVER (ORDER BY starttime DESC) IS NOT NULL THEN LAG(starttime) OVER (PARTITION BY starttime DESC) ELSE starttime END as lasttime
)
UPDATE tbldailytasks
SET 
   duration = CASE WHEN lastRecordInd = 0 THEN lasttime - starttime ELSE 0 END,
   endtime = CASE WHEN lastRecordID = 0 THEN lasttime ELSE starttime END
where taskdate =<indate>;
```

I may be a bit off and some of this logic needs somewhat newer versions of mysql, but wanted to offer up a way out of Access and row-by-row updates.

Comment: Thanks.. I am going to give this a shot.  I started thinking along the lines of using a pure SQL solution for this function, but had not pursued it yet.  I will let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

There were a couple of issues.

1. The MySQL 8.0 database version had many changes that my older version did not accommodate - one being that my autonumbers were not autonumbering.  So I rebuilt my tables to remove errors and deprecated attributes.
2. the MySQL ODBC connector has configuration options that I had forgotten needed to be set.  Primarily - a) Enable dynamic cursors and b) Return Matched rows instead of affected rows. (This is probably the most important option)

BTW - I tried a version of the the sql statement provided above and it did work nicely..  This is my version:

```
with cteDailytasks as (
select dailytaskautono, dailytaskid, starttime, endtime, duration
    , lag(starttime) over w as 'nextstart'
    , lead(starttime) over w as 'prevstart' 
 from tbldailytasks 
where taskdate = '2022-01-17'
window w as (order by starttime desc))
update tbldailytasks a,
(select dailytaskautono, nextstart, prevstart 
from cteDailyTasks) as starttimes
set a.endtime = case when starttimes.nextstart is null then a.starttime else starttimes.nextstart end, 
    a.duration = case when starttimes.nextstart is null then cast(current_date() as datetime) else cast(timediff(starttimes.nextstart,a.starttime) as datetime) end 
where a.dailytaskautono = starttimes.dailytaskautono;
```

Thanks for the replies folks.

Paul